# Extensions of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right),\ \sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}.$

Tags: field-theory, abstract-algebra

I have to solve an exercise that requires to find all extensions $\hat{\sigma}:\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\xi\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\xi\right)$
(with $\xi$ being a third root of the unity) of the field morphism

$$
\sigma:\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right),\ a+b\sqrt{2}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{2}.
$$
What I don't understand is the following:

- Shouldn't extensions of morphisms preserve the range of mapping,
  i.e. should we be looking at extensions $\hat{\sigma}:\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\xi\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$
  of the above morphism ?
- Are all the possible extensions the mappings $\hat{\sigma}_{1},\hat{\sigma}_{2}:\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\xi\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$
  given by 
  \begin{eqnarray*}
   & \hat{\sigma}_{1}:\sqrt{2}\mapsto-\sqrt{2},\ \xi\mapsto\xi\\
   & \hat{\sigma}_{2}:\sqrt{2}\mapsto-\sqrt{2},\ \xi\mapsto\xi^{2}\ ?
  \end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What you want are maps $\hat{\sigma}:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_{3})\to\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_{3})$
s.t $\hat{\sigma}|_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})}=\sigma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to extend $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_{3})$.
Since you know where $\hat{\sigma}$ maps $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$
and since the extension $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\zeta_{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$
is generated by $\zeta_{3}$all that remains is to determine $\hat{\sigma}$
of $\zeta_{3}$.

You know that $\hat{\sigma}$ needs to map $\zeta_{3}$to a conjugate
of his, there are $\phi(3)=2$ different options and you have found
both of them.

Comment: Ok, understood, thanks. Though I wonder: What is $\phi$ ?

Comment: @user47580 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: I'm glad that helps!